# How to prove this equation for moment generating function?

Tags: laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions, exponential-distribution

Let $\mathcal{L}_I(s)$ be the Laplace transform of $I$ which is given by

$\mathcal{L}_I(s)=\left(\frac{2}{r_d^2-r^2}\int_r^{r_d}\mathbb{E}_H\left[r\exp\left(-sHr^{-\eta}\right)\right]dr\right)^k$

$\mathcal{L}_I(s)=\left(\frac{2}{r_d^2-r^2}\int_r^{r_d}\mathcal{L}_H(sr^{-\eta})dr\right)^k=\left(\frac{2}{r_d^2-r^2}\int_r^{r_d}\frac{r}{(1+sr^{-\eta})}dr\right)^k$

Here, $\mathbb{E}_H$ defines the expectation over variable $H$.

It is said that when $H$ is exponentially distributed with mean 1, (i.we., $\exp(-x)$), $\mathcal{L}_I(s)$ can be expressed as

$\mathcal{L}_I(s)=\left(\frac{\Phi(\eta,s,r_d)-\Phi(\eta,s,r)}{r_d^2-r^2}\right)^k$

where,

$\Phi(\eta,s,x)=x^2-x^2\hspace{1mm} _2F_1\left(1,\hspace{1mm}2/\eta,\hspace{1mm}1+2/\eta,\hspace{1mm} -x^{\eta}/s\right)$

Here, $_2F_1$ is the Gauss Hypergeometric function.

How to prove it?

Comment: can you make $F(s) = \frac{2}{r_d^2-r^2}  \int_r^{r_d}\mathbb{E}_H\left[r\exp\left(-sHr^{-\eta}\right)\right]dr$ explicit, removing the random variable/expectation part ?

Comment: @user1952009, I do not know how to do it. Sorry,

Comment: @user1952009, Please have a look now? Is it correct?

Comment: there is a problem, namely $\int_r^{a} f(r) dr$ (what is $r$ ?), and I agree for $L_H(r)$ : if $f_H(x) = e^{-x}1_{x > 0}$ then $L_H(r) = \mathbb{E}_H[r e^{-s H r^{-\eta}}] = \int_0^\infty r e^{-s x r^{-\eta}} e^{-x} dx = \frac{r}{1+s r^{-\eta}}$. Then you have to write what is $\Phi$ in term of ${}_2F_1(-m,b;c;z) = \sum_{n=0}^m (-1)^n \binom{m}{n} \frac{(b)_n}{(c)_n} z^n$, with some luck it is just the Taylor series of your $\int_r^{r_d}L_H(s)\ldots$